# Find the particular file with path

Tags: python, python-2.6

How to use ls command to find the full path of sub directories...

Comment: And why wouldn't you want to use an approach that makes more sense? ;)

Comment: Changing the question completely after people have already answered it is not a productive way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it does seem like you're making life more difficult for yourself.  Python already has libraries to do this sort of thing for you (have a look at [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)).  If you held a gun to my head and insisted I do things your way, I would parse the output file like this:

1. Load the output file into an array, one line per array element.
2. Run down the array and look for lines that include "main.txt".
3. For each match, you need to find the directory that it's in.  You can do this by looking for a previous line that ends in ":".

You can make life significantly easier for yourself by using a different output format for `ls`.  For example, `ls -R1` is significantly easier to parse.

Comment: +1 for mentioning os.walk.  If you look at his previous questions on what appears to be this same issue you can see a pattern... good luck getting him to accept the answer.

Comment: Ah, he's pulling in the output file from a remote server.  If the server has "ls", then it also has "find", surely?

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what he is trying to-do, since he seems to be all over the place with it. Hence my comment…  And I gave a perfectly reasonable answer to one of his questions and it was basically ignored by him.